# Dealing with preimages of a function of bounded variation

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, bounded-variation

The problem is the following:

> If $f$ is a real-valued function of bounded variation on an interval $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R} $. Show that the set
> $$
> A=\{y \in \mathbb{R} : \{x \in [a, b] : f(x)=y \}\: \text{is an infinite set} \}
> $$
> has Lebesgue measure zero.

During my attempts, I felt that I was not familiar enough with functions of bounded variation and how to argue that one set has Lebesgue measure zero or not.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I have taken the liberty to change your title "A problem in ..." into a more precise one. Do you agree ?

Comment: Connected (thanks to the word "preimage") : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1546175/305862

Comment: Thank you very much! Your modification of the title has made the description of the problem more accurate.

Comment: Are there connections with this question : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/584295/305862 ?

Comment: In fact, I know this conclusion, but unfortunately, I couldn't find a connection between it and this problem during my attempts.